# Eloquent whereDate and where clause return empty

Tags: laravel

There's a few answers to this but none seem to help.

Currently I have records in my database that are before the date specified.

```
  $today = Carbon::now();
  $dtB = $today->subWeekdays(8);
```

a dd of $dtB returns: `date: 2019-09-30 11:56:44.0 America/Los_Angeles (-07:00)`

My attempt to get records from any date BEFORE where completed is NOT true is:

```
  $orders = JobStatus::orderBy('shopify_date','desc')
                          ->where('completed', '!=', 'true')
                          ->whereDate('shopify_date', '<', $dtB)
                          ->simplePaginate(25);
```

A dd of $orders returns empty.
If I remove the where clause I get the data.

Another post answer suggested removing whereDate and using where.

```
  $orders = JobStatus::orderBy('shopify_date','desc')
                          ->where('completed', '!=', 'true')
                          ->where('shopify_date', '<', $dtB)
                          ->simplePaginate(25);
```

This also returned empty.
What am I missing here?

EDIT: Date in db:

```
2019-07-18T15:59:09-07:00
```

If I do whereNull('completed) along with whereDate('shopify_date', '<', $dtB) it works.  However I need where completed not equal to 'true', the system will allow true, false or null.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `$dtB` is not in the same format as 'shopify_date', which I suppose is being stored on the database as `Y-m-d H:i:s`, correct?

With that in mind you can try using `date()` function instead of Carbon in this case. Like so:

```
$dtB = date('c', strtotime('-8 days'));
```

It will output something like `2019-09-30 16:17:15`, which is in the same format as 'shopify_date', and thus the eloquent query will probably work.

Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: It did not solve it, same, empty array returns.  @Lucas Arbex

Comment: @FabricioG Which format is 'shopify_date' being stored on the database? And also, are you sure that that are orders on the database that fill the requisites from the query?

Comment: Yes confirmed several are completed NULL and shopify_date under 09/30

Comment: @FabricioG try using 'c' instead of 'Y-m-d H:i:s' (check my updated answer)... and see if it works now, please...

Comment: Main thing is thou when I remove the where('completed', '!=', 'true') it gets the records.  So the $dtB is ok.

Comment: @FabricioG is the date working now? And regarding `('completed', '!=', 'true')` be careful using quotes. You are checking in this case if completed is different of the string 'true'...

Comment: The original way the code is the date works.  I stated this in the original question: A dd of $orders returns empty. If I remove the where clause I get the data.  The quotes 'true' is because in the db it's set to varchar.

Comment: @FabricioG so if the date is working since the beggining, why did you mention the date and Carbon in your question in the first place?

Comment: A dd of $orders returns empty. If I remove the where clause I get the data.  That's exactly what it says and has said.

Comment: @FabricioG I get that. I just don't understand why you've mentioned all that stuff about the date if the problem is with `->where('completed', '!=', 'true')`...